# EE contact form - interact with POST data before sending email

Tags: ee3, php, email-contact-form

We're running ExpressionEngine 3.5.17 and using the in-built contact form.

We have a requirement whereby if someone completes the "From" email address on the form, and it originates from a certain domain - let's say `example.com` - the email should not be sent.

The problem with this is I can't see what to modify/extend in EE which would make this possible.

The form is fairly basic in that we are using tags in a template:

```
{exp:email:contact_form recipients="foo@bar.com" form_id="downloadResourceForm" redirect="none" charset="utf-8"} 

    <!-- Form fields -->

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required>

    <!-- More form fields -->

{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

I understand that in vanilla PHP I could access the "email" field in the POST data with `$_POST['email']`. However I don't know how to interact with this because EE is handling the form submission via it's own scripts.

I'm also aware of not modifying EE core files - so how do you "override" the EE code in a way that makes upgrades safe?

Answer (score 0):

In stead of using in built `exp:email:contact_form` modifying core files of EE I am suggesting you to use [FormGrab](https://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/formgrab). This plugin is very simple and easy to use. You can create and integrate **Contact form** very easily.

To achieve your requirement **(interact with POST)** this plugin has hook from which you can modify and validate the data by creating simple extension file.

And main thing is, it comes up with no Cost. **It is free.** I think this plugin suits your requirement.